# Exact copy of sidebar template doesn't look the same

Tags: wordpress, templates

I am using the twenty eleven theme for a website. I am trying to make a copy of the sidebar template but with a different sidebar in it. I copied the code in sidebar-page.php and changed the template name. I haven't made a new sidebar yet so that's not the problem. It is an exact copy of sidebar-page.php right now but with a new name.

Still when I use the new template for a page it does not look the same as it does on my other sidebar pages. Have I missed something? It is driving me crazy.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Artist Template
 * Description: The artist page with a custom sidebar
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Eleven
 * @since Twenty Eleven 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary">
        <div id="content" role="main">

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

                <?php //comments_template( '', true ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?> 
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: what did you try ? show some code

Comment: did you put the widget inside the new sidebar? did you changed its registered name ``??

Comment: Did you try making a backup of the file and working on the original?

Comment: I have updated this post with some code =) I have not made any changes to the sidebar yet just tried to copy the original sidebar template.